# Display in category ( taxonomy) a number of post that I want

Tags: posts, archives

How can I display a number of 20 posts in my Page Archive (Taxonomy Archive)?

For example: in wordpress settings in Reading I use: Blog pages show at most 10 posts.
This works in arhive page, but when I click on the categories (taxonomy's) it display only 10 posts.

I have this function that displays the archive:

```
function iti_custom_posts_per_page($query)
    {
        switch ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] )
        {
            case 'trailers':  // Post Type named 'iti_cpt_1'
                $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 20;
                break;

            case 'persoane':  // Post Type named 'iti_cpt_2'
                $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 6;
                break;


            case 'serial':  // Post Type named 'iti_cpt_3'
                $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 6;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return $query;
    }

    if( !is_admin() )
    {
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'iti_custom_posts_per_page' );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you seem to have the code that seems close to what you want, but doesn't function correctly. What I have trouble following is that your description talks about taxonomy archives, but your code seems to be about custom post type archives.

I would suggest to use more appropriate query methods rather than working with vars directly:

- `$query->is_tax()` to check for taxonomy archives
- `$query->is_post_type_archive()` to check for CPT archives
- `$query->set()` to modify query vars